# lombucci/jwt It was not possible to parse your key, reason: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: php, jwt, metabase

lombucci/jwt 4.1.5
PHP 8.0.10

Getting the following issue when attempting to create a token

```
It was not possible to parse your key, reason: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

Here is a class that can be used to recreate this issue

(token has been modified for the demo if that matters)

```
<?php

namespace Domain\MetaBase;

use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key\InMemory;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;

class Metabase
{
    public function generateToken(): string
    {
        $metabaseSiteUrl = "https://potato.metabaseapp.com";
        $metabaseSecretKey = "1690e6bf587bc61b5cdd3897c143291caa48779cc7abef104abf952fec6e8d4a";
        $now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $config = Configuration::forSymmetricSigner(new Sha256(), InMemory::plainText($metabaseSecretKey));
        $token = $config->builder()
            ->issuedBy($metabaseSiteUrl)
            ->withHeader('iss', $metabaseSiteUrl)
            ->permittedFor($metabaseSiteUrl)
            ->issuedAt($now)
            ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter($now->modify('+1 minute'))
            ->expiresAt($now->modify('+1 hour'))
            ->withClaim('resource', ['question' => 15])

            //METABASE resource (question, card, dashboard)
            ->withClaim('params', ['cod_usuario' => 1001])

            //METABASE params variables metabase
            ->getToken($config->signer(), $config->signingKey());

        return $metabaseSiteUrl . "/embed/question/" . $token->toString() . "#bordered=true&titled=true";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue I was having was that I was using

```
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;
```

when I should have been using

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me solution was, instead of creating public/private key with ssh, it should created by openssl

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

then

```
openssl rsa -pubout -in private.pem -out public.pem
```

done